# In my JUnit test, how do I verify a Spring RedirectView?

Tags: spring, junit, modelandview

I'm using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and JUnit 4.11.  In a particular Spring controller, I have a method that ends thusly ...

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(redirectUri, true));
```

In my JUnit test, how do I verify return from a submission to my controller in which this RedirectView is returned?  I used to use org.springframework.test.web.AbstractModelAndViewTests.assertViewName, but that only returns "null", even when a non-empty ModelAndView object is returned.  Here is how I'm constructing my JUnit test ...

```
    request.setRequestURI(“/mypage/launch");
    request.setMethod("POST");
    …
   final Object handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
    final ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response,  handler);
    assertViewName(mav, "redirect:/landing");
```

Any help on how to verify that a RedirectView comes back with the proper value is appreciatd,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Koiter said, consider moving to spring-test a and [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html)

It providers some methods to test controllers and requests/reponses in a declarative way

you will need a `@Autowired WebApplicationContext wac;`

and on your `@Before` method setup this to use the `@WebAppConfiguration` of the class.

You'll end up with something

```
 @ContextConfiguration("youconfighere.xml")
 //or (classes = {YourClassConfig.class}
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @WebAppConfiguration
 public class MyControllerTests {

 @Autowired WebApplicationContext wac
 private MockMvc mockMvc;


 @Before
 public void setup() {
      //setup the mock to use the web context
      this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build(); 
   }
}
```

Then you just need to use the [MockMvcResultMatchers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#redirectedUrl-java.lang.String-) to assert things

```
 @Test
  public void testMyRedirect() throws Exception {
   mockMvc.perform(post("you/url/")
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(redirectUrl("you/redirect")
}
```

Note: `post(), status() isOk() redirectUrl()` are statics imports from `MockMvcResultMatchers`

See more what you can match [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html)

Comment: In Spring 1.3.5 the static function is "redirectedUrl"

Answer (score 0):

Considering change your tool to MockMvc.

First you should create your MockMvc based on your controller.

```
private MockMvc mockController;

    mockController =
            MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).setCustomArgumentResolvers(
                    new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(new PageableArgumentResolver())).build();
```

After you create that object build the request with the request information. Part of this is the assert options that are contained in the API.

```
mockController.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(LoginControllerTest.LOGIN_CONTROLLER_URL + "?logout=true").
                principal(SessionProvider.getPrincipal("GonLu004")))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("jsp/login"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("logOutMessage", logoutMessage));
```

The [MockMvcResultMatchers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html) contains a method for reviewing redirect [information](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/redirect/RedirectControllerTests.java).

[MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) from spring is a good choice to apply your unit testing on the controller layer.